# What is the difference between "Seem focused on" and "Seem to be focused on"?

Tags: expressions

And also, is the expression "seem focusing on doing something" also correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seem) provides this example for the verb seem:

> He's 16, but he often seems (to be) younger.

The brackets indicate that "to be" is optional: the meaning is the same whether it is included or not. This is just a quirk of the word "seem". "Look" can have the same meaning, but this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seems%20to%20be%2Clooks%20to%20be&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that, while the "to be" version does occur, it is very uncommon.

We can use the past participle **focused** directly after "seem" or with a "to be", but the present participle **focusing** cannot appear directly after "seem": a "to be" is required, as in "..seems to be focusing on...". Here is an [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seems%20focused%2Cseems%20focusing%2C%20seems%20to%20be%20focusing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) that shows the relative frequency of usage.